# Google Sheet CountIFS - how to include and exclude at same time?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google Sheet

Table List: Devices

A2=iPhone 6s Jupiter

A3=iPhone 6s Road

A4=iPhone 6s Plus Melanholia

Table list: New

A2=iPhone 6s

```
B2=Countifs(Devices!A1:A;"*"&A2&"<>*Plus*")
```

**Result 0**

I want to show count of all **iPhone 6s** from cell A2 and exclude all matches if iPhone 6s have **Plus**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HS0Q9ZlAoOe7EfyhiwHqsFxkw3lEqbFXYm0BziqInGY/edit#gid=513313065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at concatenation result you will see:

```
*iPhone 6s<>*Plus*
```

which will be `false` in all cases.

To count all IPones except PLUS, use:

```
=countifs(Devices!A:A;"*"&A2&"*";Devices!A:A;"<>*PLUS*")
```

[image]